# How to stop Sphinx automethod prefixing method name with class name

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

When I use Sphinx automethod to document a specific method like so:

```
.. automethod:: my_module.MyClass.my_method
```

The resulting docs append the class name to the method name like this:

```
MyClass.my_method(kwarg1=None, kwarg2=None)

    This is the docstring for my_method...
```

Is there any way to tell automethod to *not* prefix the method name with the class name, such that the resulting docs look like this:

```
my_method(kwarg1=None, kwarg2=None)

    This is the docstring for my_method...
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to

```
add_module_names = False
```

use

```
.. autofunction:: my_module.MyClass.my_method
```

instead of `automodule` and the class name is omitted in the generated doc.

Answer (score 6):

Add this line in your `conf.py` file

`add_module_names = False`